# Could this glass crack in a window have been caused by a physical impact?

Tags: windows, crack, glass

I live in a rented apartment and have noticed a glass crack in a window, so I'm trying to figure out whether I damaged the glass or it somehow got damaged on its own (for example, by thermal stress), in order to decide how to talk to the landlord about it.

The crack is in the inner pane of a double-paned window and looks pretty unusual, unlike a "normal" glass crack. Here's a photo (in which I put a piece of paper on the glass to make the camera focus on the glass):

[image]

The photo was taken when the camera was oriented parallel to the window - that is, the line of sight was perpendicular to the window.

As you can see in this photo, the crack is an ideally straight line that goes exactly vertically, getting thinner towards the ends, and is about 15 cm long and 1 mm wide. The crack looks as if it were a long cavity filled with air or water, no matter the angle you look at it, so I'm unsure whether it's really a crack or something else. And when I touch it with my finger, I don't feel any surface irregularity whatsoever, so the damage seems to be entirely inside the glass. The crack is near the center of the window, so both ends of the crack are far from the frame.

I wouldn't suspect myself of damaging the window if I hadn't recently killed an insect on it with my finger. The impact of my finger was so mild that no one would ever expect any glass damage, and I didn't see any crack appear when I killed the insect. Neither did I hear any crack sound. But the crack is pretty much where I killed the insect, and I noticed the crack about an hour after I killed the insect, so I'm at a loss as to whether the crack is due to that impact. I've never really paid attention to that window, so I can't exclude that the crack was already there when I moved in.

My question: Based on what the crack looks like, can I exclude the possibility of it having been caused by that physical impact of my finger? Could a glass crack due to an impact look like this? What could have caused such a crack?

Comment: I'm not convinced that it is a crack -- a bit too straight.  I would suspect that it's some sort of manufacturing  defect.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that it is safety glass.  Safety glass is required in such an area here in NZ, in case running children go smack into them.

Even for normal glass, but especially for safety glass (from experience).  If you damage it, there is a point of impact and you get a radial pattern of fractures.

This looks more like stress in the glass from manufacture or stress due to installation.

Heres an article on [impact fractures](https://modernforensic.in/glass-fracture-and-3r-rule-of-glass-fracture/) and it mentions 3 patterns.

> 1. RADIAL FRACTURE: the penetration of ordinary window glass by a projectile, whether it is bullet or stone, produce a fracture pattern which radiates outwards like a spoke of wheel from the point at which glass was stuck.
> 2. CONCENTRIC FRACTURE:   the concentric glass fractures are the secondary fracture and occur after radial fracture. If the force continues even after the radial fracture, the tensile stress develops on the side where the force was applied. This leads to series of concentric circles around the point of contact known as concentric fracture.
> 3. CONE FRACTURE: this type of crack or fracture is formed when a high velocity projectile object such as bullet  penetrates the glass which exceeds its  elasticity limit. It often leaves a round crater shaped hole surrounded by radial and concentric fractures.

Comment: Agreed, from what I see in the picture this looks like a manufacturing flaw.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the vertical crack.

What I do see are multiple almost horizontal scratches, which make me believe it is not glass but acrylic window.

The multiple horizontal scratches come from cleaning the window from the bug massacre committed and by using abrasive cleaning method.

[image: window]

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the image (as I initially did). The crack is viewed here from the side. If you're familiar with cracks in lake ice seen from the side you know what I mean. The scratches may simply be streaks.

Comment: I've just marked the crack in my photo and added another photo

Comment: I guess you took the actual crack for some object located outside. The photo was taken from a very close distance, so this thick vertical line going across the entire photo is the crack